# Get value from function body parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have typescript function that takes function

```
GetOne<T>(predicate: (e: T) => boolean): T;

var user = GetOne<IUser>(a => a.Id === this.id);
```

predicate toString() returns "function (a) { return a.Id === _this.id; }"

how can i get value from "_this.id" ?

I would like to make a breezejs Predicate from that function informations...

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get `this.Id` value from the predicate. The only way I can see here is to pass `breezejs Predicate` as predicate parameter

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript/ES6 arrow function, this refer to the instance of the class. So you may just use yourInstance.id to get the id.

Answer (score 0):

This Code

```
GetOne<T>(predicate: (e: T) => boolean): T;

var user = GetOne<IUser>(a => a.Id === this.id);
```

is equals to

```
GetOne<T>(predicate: (e: T) => boolean): T;
var self = this;
var user = GetOne<IUser>(function(a){ return a.Id === self.id });
```

if your question is how you can get the this (e.g. user) of the anyonym function (a) ... that is maybe called with

```
predicate.call(user);
// or
predicate.apply(user);
```

then you has to rewrite your code to

```
GetOne<T>(predicate: (e: T) => boolean): T;

var user = GetOne<IUser>(function(a){ return a.Id === this.id });
```